# Negative top margin will not work on child image

Tags: css, parent-child, margin

This is what I want the chicklet box to look like:![][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21t9O.jpg)
For some reason I can not use negative margins to get the twitter image to go to the center of the box. Is there something wrong with my parent-child relationship?

My css is in an external sheet, but here it is:

```
<style type="text/css">

#chicklet_container {
    margin:20px auto 0px auto;
    width:540px;
    height:215px;
}

#chicklet_box {
    margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    width:190px;
    height:160px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:33px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-color:#45BA88;
    position:relative;
}

#chicklet_box2 {
    margin:-30px 0px 10px 0px;
    width:190px;
    height:160px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0px 0px 30px 0px;
    border-color:#3f4040;
}

#chicklet_text {
    text-align:center;
    margin:-196px 0px 0px 0px;
    color:#FFF;
    width:190px;
    font-family:"Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif";
    font-size:27px;
    line-height:20px;
}

#chicklet_text2 {
    text-align:center;
    margin:139px 0px 0px 0px;
    color:#FFF;
    width:190px;
    font-family:"Proxima, Nova, Ultralight";
    font-size:26px;
    line-height:20px;
}

#chicklet_box img {
    margin:-250px 0px auto 5px;
}
</style>
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="chicklet_container">
    <div id="chicklet_box">
        <div id="chicklet_box2">
        </div>
            <div id="chicklet_text">Follow Me</div>
            <div id="chicklet_text2">@soandsoandso</div>
            <img src="images/twitter.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the image you're using, or at least tell us the size so that we can test it?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using so much margin to align the twitter bird image or text. Use as low margins as possible. Instead this, try using that image `position:absolute;` and top ,left properties. It'll be more clean. But one thing to remember if you are using absolute position for an element ,check if its outer or parent element is positioned or not, if it is not then things may go worse and that child element might go somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Negative margins are not a hack - W3C even says: "Negative values for margin properties are allowed..."

Read More: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

I do agree in this case though they may be over-emphasized.

Why do you have Chicklet Box 2 inside of Chicklet Box 1? I'm assuming each box represents an icon... am I wrong?